# 'half' function type signature in Idris

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I'm pretty new to Idris and I'm trying to catch the basic concepts and syntax.

Even if it may sound pointless, I'm trying to define a `half` function which is halving a natural.

I wish to come up with something like:

```
half : (n : Nat) -> (k : Nat) -> (n = k + k) -> (k : Nat)
```

but of course it's not working. Specifically I get:

> error: expected: dependent type signature
>
> ```
> half : (n : Nat) -> (k : Nat) -> (n = k + k) -> (k : Nat)
> ```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is to express that `half n` is some `Nat`ural number `k` such that `n = k + k` holds. The way to do it is by using a [sigma type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#Dependent_pair_type), i.e. a dependent pair of a number `k` and a proof `n = k + k` (it's a dependent pair because the *type* of the second coordinate, `n = k + k` depends on the *value* of the first coordinate, `k`).

The Idris standard library defines [`DPair`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/v0.12.3/libs/prelude/Builtins.idr#L40) for depedent pairs, including some syntax sugar allowing you to write

```
half : (n : Nat) -> (k ** n = k + k)
```

However, note that you won't be able to implement `half` (as a total function) because there's no good answer to e.g. `half 1`. Maybe what you want is

```
half : (n : Nat) -> (k ** Either (n = k + k) (n = k + k + 1))
```

?

Comment: Well, thanks, it typechecks indeed. Anyway, what I want to express is something like `half: (n : Nat) -> Even n -> Nat` with the additional information that the resulting `Nat` is actually the first `Nat` halved. In your case, is the function total (i.e. taking in input only even `Nat`)? The fact that you use `Eirther` make me think that it is not, while in the first version we have to provide `half` with a proof the `n` is even, which leave out 1, 3 and all the other odd numbers. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The second version can be made total, since every `n` is either `2 * k` or `2 * k + 1`. Of course the first one can't, since there's no `k` such that e.g. `1 = 2 * k`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use k twice.
half : (n : Nat) -> (k : Nat) -> (n = k + k) -> Nat
is correct, but useless.
I think you need
half : (n : Nat) -> Maybe (k ** n = k + k)